# Bot that sends a custom message based on users discord ID

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py, bots, webhooks

I have a code that sends a message everytime someone mention him. I would like to grab some members of my discord, and do custom messages for them.

I imagine i could do this by getting their discord ID, and making the bot recognizes it and send the message i want it to send, but how do i do it?

Comment: Please provide some code of what you've done to try to accomplish this. An example of what is going on but not going right is a good place to start!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've understand on your question. You wanted to get a random member then send a custom message, you need to use `message.guild.members.cache.random();`

```
const member = message.guild.members.cache.random();
```

after that create your custom message on array.

```
const sentence = [
   "Something 1",
   "Something 2",
   "Something 3",
   "Something 4"
]
```

And make a `Math.random` to take one of the message in your `array`

```
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * sentence.length)
```

now create your body

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${sentence[random]}`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTimestamp()

message.channel.send({content: `${member.user.username}`, embeds: [embed]})
```

You can create your unique message to. Instead of `array` use `args`

```
const sentence = args.slice(0).join(" ")
```

Full code:

```
const member = message.guild.members.cache.random();
    const sentence = [
        "Something 1",
        "Something 2",
        "Something 3",
        "Something 4"
    ]

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * sentence.length)

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${sentence[random]}`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTimestamp()

    message.channel.send({content: `${member.user.username}`, embeds: [embed]})
```

**PS:** Don't just copy paste it, understand it and its functions